# how to create Keras multi LSTM layer using for loop?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I'm trying to implement a multi layer `LSTM` in **Keras** using **for loop** and [this](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/19_Hyper-Parameters.ipynb) tutorial to be able to optimize the number of layers, which is obviously a hyper-parameter. In the tutorial, the author used `skopt` for `hyper-parameter optimization`. I used Functional API to create my model. For simplicity, I changed `input_tensor`'s shape to arbitrary values.  My model is:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM, Input
from keras.models import Model

from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform, glorot_normal, RandomUniform


input_tensor = Input(shape=(10, 20))

def create_model(learning_rate, num_lstm_layers, num_lstm_units, activation):
    init = glorot_normal(seed=None)
    init1 = RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05)

    x = Input(shape=(10, 20))


    for i in range(num_lstm_layers):

        name = 'layer_lstm_{0}'.format(i+1)

        if( (i==0) and (num_lstm_layers==1) ):
            x = LSTM(units=num_lstm_units, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, 
                    return_sequences=False, kernel_initializer=init, 
                    activation=activation, name=name)(x)
        elif(i != (num_lstm_layers-1) ):
            x = LSTM(units=num_lstm_units, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,  
                    return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer=init, 
                    activation=activation, name=name)(x)
        else:
            x = LSTM(units=num_lstm_units, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,  
                    return_sequences=False, kernel_initializer=init, 
                    activation=activation, name=name)(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer= init1)(x)

    model = Model(input_tensor, x)

    optimizer = RMSprop(lr=learning_rate, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'] )

    return model
```

Whenever I try to fit the model to the data, I encounter this error :

> ValueError: Initializer for variable layer_lstm_1_14/kernel/ is from
>   inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When
>   creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the
>   initializer.

So far, I've known that somewhere I should add a `lambda` function or `keras Lambda layer`. 
Also, I tested the model in a separate python script, like below:

```
model = create_model(learning_rate=1e-3, num_lstm_layers=3, num_lstm_units=64, activation='linear')
```

But again it gives me this error:

> ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor
>   Tensor("input_2:0", shape=(?, 10, 20), dtype=float32) at layer
>   "input_2". The following previous layers were accessed without issue:
>   []

I Also tried to create `Sequential` version of the model. But encountered the same error.

**EDIT1:**
Edited if statement from  `if( i==0)`: to  `if( (i==0) and (num_lstm_layers==1) ):` By doing so and making the changes André suggested, you are able to create LSTM models using for loop.

Comment: I don't think your for-loop is at fault here. Keras doesn't know that you used a for-loop to create the model. Try to hard code a few of the loops of the model building. I'm pretty sure you're still going to get the same error. If not then you know that loop is at fault.

Comment: Another thing which seems off is that you have `input_tensor` outside of the create function, then create a new one inside which you don't give to the model. I'll try to type out an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in the comments, I'm not worried about your for-loop, but rather the input. I'm not 100% sure, but think that you should try to delete

```
input_tensor = Input(shape=(10, 20))
```

... which comes before the `create_model(...)` function and edit the creation of the one inside as follows:

```
input_tensor = x = Input(shape=(10, 20))
```

Reading on, you say you get `Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor`. That definitely sounds like you're input isn't connected. The change I suggest should connect your input and output (respectively the first and second argument of `Model(...)`).

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer, André. It solved my problem and I'm now able to get model.summary() . Now I face a new Issue when try to fit the model. When I try to fit the model to my data, it produces this error:`NotFoundError: FeedInputs: unable to find feed output input_layer:0.
` . Should I post it as a new question?

Comment: No problem. Yeah. I think that would be prudent. Make another question, with new code, and comment the new link here and I'll have a look.