# Error with saving keras model after hyper-parameter optimization using skopt

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm following [this](https://github.com/Hvass-Labs/TensorFlow-Tutorials/blob/master/19_Hyper-Parameters.ipynb) tutorial to optimize my model's hyper-parameters. After posting a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51811797/how-to-create-keras-multi-lstm-layer-using-for-loop) and getting immediate answer, I successfully created a multi layer `LSTM` model with for loop. below is my final model:

```
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM, Input
from keras.models import Model

from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform, glorot_normal, RandomUniform



def create_model(learning_rate, num_lstm_layers, num_lstm_units, activation):
    init = glorot_normal(seed=None)
    init1 = RandomUniform(minval=-0.05, maxval=0.05)
    input_tensor_mine = x = Input(shape=(x_train.shape[1], x_train.shape[2]), name='input_layerrrr')

    for i in range(num_lstm_layers):

        name = 'layer_lstm_{0}'.format(i+1)

        if( (i==0) and (num_lstm_layers==1) ):
            x = LSTM(units=num_lstm_units, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2, 
                    return_sequences=False, kernel_initializer=init, 
                    activation=activation, name=name)(input_tensor_mine)
        elif(i != (num_lstm_layers-1) ):
            x = LSTM(units=num_lstm_units, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,  
                    return_sequences=True, kernel_initializer=init, 
                    activation=activation, name=name)(x)
        else:
            x = LSTM(units=num_lstm_units, dropout=0.2, recurrent_dropout=0.2,  
                    return_sequences=False, kernel_initializer=init, 
                    activation=activation, name=name)(x)
    x = Dense(1, activation='linear', kernel_initializer= init1)(x)

    model = Model(input_tensor_mine, x)

    optimizer = RMSprop(lr=learning_rate, rho=0.9, epsilon=None, decay=0.0)
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=['mse'] )
    print(model.summary())
    return model
```

Then I continued to write my own code for the `fitness` function described in the aforementioned tutorial:

```
path_best_model = 'best_model.keras'
best_mse=10

@use_named_args(dimensions=dimensions)
def fitness(learning_rate, num_lstm_layers, num_lstm_units, activation):

    model = create_model(learning_rate=learning_rate,
                         num_lstm_layers=num_lstm_layers,
                         num_lstm_units=num_lstm_units,
                         activation=activation)
    history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3, 
                        batch_size=64, 
                        validation_data=(x_test, y_test),
                        shuffle=False)
    mse = history.history['val_loss'][-1]
    global best_mse

    if mse<best_mse:
        model.save(path_best_model)
        best_mse = mse

    del model
    K.clear_session()

    return mse
```

**My problem** is that if `model.save(path_best_model)` is not commented out and I run the **fitness** function, after creating 3 automatic models by `gp_minimize`, I get the error below:

```
#running the automatic creation of LSTM models using gp_minimize and fitness function

from skopt import gp_minimize
search_result = gp_minimize(func=fitness,
                            dimensions=dimensions,
                            acq_func='EI',
                            n_calls=40,
                            x0=default_parameters)
```

> ## error:
>
> ValueError: Fetch argument  cannot be
>   interpreted as a Tensor. (Tensor Tensor("layer_lstm_1/kernel:0",
>   shape=(331, 188), dtype=float32_ref) is not an element of this graph.)

If anyone wants to know more details about 3 created models, I'll add `model.summary()` of them to the question.